# how to get jquery object in unsorted manner

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object as below. When I use the for loop, i get the keys as sorted. How do i get the keys so that they are not sorted?

```
  var obj= {
      "2": "John",
      "1": "Fox",
      "3": "David",
      "0":"Joe",
    }

for(var key in obj) alert(key);
```

Comment: An object does not have a defined order, you can't trust it will always be sorted in same way

Comment: There's no way to control the order of keys in an object.

Comment: if you store the literal as JSON, you can use a reviver callback on JSON.parse to re-define key order at instantiation time.

Comment: @dandavis: Only if it's an array, not an object.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: you're right that going back into the fire of an object won't help. But, the parse callback could let you turn the object into an array of two-element arrays, jump right to the append routine with ordering considered, etc. there is opportunity there...

Comment: it would be possible and perhaps useful if someone could create a order-preserving object using Object.observe and a hidden LUT variable. it could be fed JSON instead of literals, and defining new props would append to the end of the hidden LUT. This could power an Object.keysInOrder() method that would be reliable and handy in many situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use you object as

```
var obj = {
  "_2": "John",
  "_1": "Fox",
  "_3": "David",
  "_0": "Joe"
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works differently from the original?

Comment: V8 re-orders numerical object properties. it's only different in V8 afaik... use an array if you want sorted numerical keys, or two arrays if you want a custom sort.

Comment: @Barmar iteration is in the order of definition of the keys which are strings.Numeric keys are sorted first and then string keys. this is applicable for IE9 and chrome

Comment: And it's an implementation detail which should not be relied upon.

Answer (score 2):

Use Array Structure and Not Object Structure  to conserve the order:

So :

```
  var myArray=[
      {"2": "John"},
      {"1": "Fox"},
      {"3": "David"},
      {"0":"Joe"}
   ]
```

then :

```
for(var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
  for(var key in myArray[i])
  alert(key)
}
```

OR :

```
for(var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){

  alert(Object.keys(myArray[i])[0])

}
```

OR

```
 myArray.map(function(e){alert(Object.keys(e)[0]) })
```

**UPDATE :**

If Keys Of Object is used just for index, It is enough to Use an array indexed by value of key without persisting those keys, That it means :

```
  var myArray=[
      {"2": "John"},
      {"1": "Fox"},
      {"3": "David"},
      {"0":"Joe"}
   ]
```

Quite simply,it Becomes:

```
  var myArray=[
       "Joe",
       "Fox",
       "John",
        "David"

   ]
```

Comment: that's much harder (nested) to iterate than need be. consider { "2": [0,"John"] } instead...

Comment: If i use    for(var i in myArray) alert("i value "+i); i get 0,1,2,3 which are in sorted order, i dont need it that way.

Comment: @mistack305: Please look at the code in the answer again. What you are doing is not correct and it's not what the answer suggests to do. It's no wonder that you don't get the expected results if you are not doing what you are advised to do.

Comment: @mistack305 : (var i in array) does not conserver order. So that , We use(var i=0;i<lengthArry;i++) . Right ?

Comment: the more i consider it, the more i think something simple is apropos: [["0","Joe"],["1","Fox"],["2","John"],["3","David"]]. then you can use [].map() or a "i++<length" for loop to iterate and splice to re-order.

Comment: @dandavis: Completely agree. Having an object with a single property just for the sake of having a key doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @AbdennourToumi you are correct. But what about the performance since it was nested for loops?

Comment: Ah. i have imitate your question to understande.. So , see to Update after 1 min